# Substring using Oracle When there is multiple Matches?

Tags: oracle

Hi I am trying to fetch substring in oracle for the below two strings. I want result if the pattern matches starting with S9C and the having 8 numbers after S9C

For Eg: for the below two inputs I need output like

Input:

```
 1.CABLE : THERMINAL 3X2X0.25MM FPCP PLUS UNITRONIC S9C000019651  
 2.Motor Protection Relay EMR-3MPO-2S9CB1-1 (was IQ1000II / MP 3000)
 3.GREASE : BEM 41-132 3KG CARTRIDGE KLUBERPLEX S9C00019171 (Order by KG's required)
 4.DO NOT USE CARRIER SPIDEX ZK 38 98 SH. S9C00011593 (SUPERSEDE BY S9C10204555 - WIN0020775)
```

Output:

```
1.Null
2.Null
3.S9C00019171
4.S9C10204555
```

Comment: "starting with S9C and the having 8 numbers after A9B" - excuse me, but - there's no A9B in sample data you posted at all, so **all** outputs should be NULL.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of `REGEXP_SUBSTR` and `REGEXP_COUNT` to solve your question:

```sql
WITH test_data(input) AS
(
  SELECT  '1.CABLE : THERMINAL 3X2X0.25MM FPCP PLUS UNITRONIC S9C000019651' FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
  SELECT  '2.Motor Protection Relay EMR-3MPO-2S9CB1-1 (was IQ1000II / MP 3000)' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT  '3.GREASE : BEM 41-132 3KG CARTRIDGE KLUBERPLEX S9C00019171 (Order by KG''s required)' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT  '4.DO NOT USE CARRIER SPIDEX ZK 38 98 SH. S9C00011593 (SUPERSEDE BY S9C10204555 - WIN0020775)' FROM DUAL
)
SELECT regexp_substr(td.input, 
                     'S9C[0-9]{8}( |$)', 
                     1, 
                     GREATEST(1, regexp_count(td.input, 'S9C[0-9]{8}( |$)')))
FROM test_data td
```

Here's a quick explanation of how it works:

1. `REGEXP_COUNT` counts the occurrences of the target pattern, so we can get the last occurrence later.
2. Wrap the result in in `GREATEST` because 0 is invalid for `REGEXP_SUBSTR` parameter.
3. Call `REGEXP_SUBSTR` to grab the last occurrence of the target string.

Here is a DBFiddle to show you it working ([DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=27a2027e3278ff0d5f8d2804867c57b5))